# Evaluate $\int\frac{1}{r \ln(r)} \ dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the antiderivative of

$$\int\frac{1}{r \ln(r)} \ dr$$

I'm trying to use substitution, but substituting $u=r$ doesn't help as that just changes the variable.

Comment: Try using $u=\ln(r)$.

Comment: One last hint: $\dfrac{1}{r \ln r} = \dfrac{1}{r} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\ln r}$.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, try the substitution $u = \ln (r)$. Then, $du = \frac{1}{r} \ dr$.

$$\int\frac{1}{r \ln(r)} \ dr = \int\frac{du}{u} = \ln(u) + C = \ln\left(\ln(r)\right) + C$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the substitution $u=\ln(r)$,

Then $u'=\frac1r$

Have you tried that?